# Making Span stick to the top

Tags: css

I have the following elements, that displays live games on my page.

```
<div class="event-top">
<a href=".." class="event-match">
<span class="event-time">25/01 07:00pm</span>
<span class="event-name">Ironi Ramat Hasharon 0-0 Hapoel Natzrat-Elite</span>
<span class="event-league"> - Leumit League - Israel - Football</span>
<span class="event-more">DETAILS</span>
</a>
</div>
```

The css is pretty straight forward:

```
.event-match {
display: block;
}
.event-more {
float:right;
```

I'm trying to make the event-more text stick to the top right area, even when screen size become small enough to make the event-name and event-league break into two lines, but the first thing that happens when screen size gets smaller, is DETAILS goes to a new line. How do I keep it in place? I feel I've tried everyting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the element `absolute`

```
.event-match {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
}
.event-more {
    background-color: green;
    top: 0; // you can adjust top and right to suit your needs.
    right: 0; 
    position: absolute;
}
```